# How do I remove a product page SKU in Magennto2

Tags: sku

how to remove sku on product page in magento2[image]

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks

Comment: If answer help, upvote and accept as solution. so this will help other in community.

Answer (score 1):

Create layout file on your current theme fo the product page:

> app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml

Then, added this code in the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method To Remove SKU from Product Page in Magento 2:**

Create `catalog_product_view.xml` file at `app\design\frontend\[Vendor]\[Theme]\Magento_Catalog\layout`

Or in your module

`app\code\[Vendor]\[Module]\view\frontend\layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

That’s all to hide SKU from the product page in Magento 2.

For more info click [here](https://meetanshi.com/blog/remove-sku-from-product-page-in-magento-2/)

Comment: Should this method be written in a custom module or in a theme? Why

Comment: Yes you can add in your module also check updated code